# Finding the domain of the following integral in polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

**Question:** Convert the following integral into polar coordinates and solve $$\int_0^\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\int_x^\sqrt{1-x^2}xy \ dy\,dx$$

**My attempt:**

I managed to get this: $$\int_0^1\int_\frac{\pi}{4}^\frac{\pi}{2} r^3\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta) \ d\theta\,dr$$

However I feel that I am wrong because surely there must some dependence between $r$ and $\theta$. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: No. This is fine. Draw the picture. You are just trying to compute the area of a nice sector.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Do you have any tips on how to check your domain after you've calculated it

Comment: Drawing the image is the best way. You have to come up with the domain when switching. The sector that comes about, if you draw it, has exactly those properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is the upper semicircle of radius $1$ and $y= x$ is the line through the origin. The intersection between the curves is $\sqrt{1-x^2}=x$ that is $x=\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$. So the domain of integration is the sector in the picture for $r\in[0,1]$ and $\theta\in\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$:

[image]

So your integral in polar coordinates will de
$$
\int_0^1\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}r^3\cos\theta\sin\theta \,\mathrm d \theta\,\mathrm d r=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 r^3\,\mathrm d r=\frac{1}{16}
$$

As check you can evaluate the original integral
$$\int_0^\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\int_x^\sqrt{1-x^2}xy \,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}x\left(\frac{1}{2}-x^2\right)\,\mathrm dx=\frac{1}{16}$$